# Are custom objects enabled on Salesforce Essential Edition

Tags: custom-object, developer, sales, editions, create

This is a quick question. Is it possible to create custom Object in Salesforce Essential Edition?

If so, is there a way to enable it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look at the [Salesforce Help doc on creating a custom object](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.dev_objectcreate_task_lex.htm&type=5), you can see that Essentials is not supported

> REQUIRED EDITIONS AND USER PERMISSIONS
>
> Available in: Lightning Experience
>
> Available in: Contact Manager, Group, Professional, Enterprise, Performance, Unlimited, and Developer Editions

You need to upgrade to one of those editions.

Comment: Thanks! That's what I wanted to know. If I upgrade to Professional, the objects I create can be seen by Essential Licenses?

Comment: if you upgrade to Professional that applies to the entire org and Essentials licenses get converted to Professional